# How can i get only image size from remote url in android?

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

I want to get image size from url.
Only i know is that decode entire bitmap and get size from it.

but i want get only image size.

is there any good way..?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not possible without downloading the image first. When it grabs the image resource from a website, it could be a multi megabyte high resolution quality image or a tiny icon. Its all the same until the download starts.

Comment: I guess i could get image size from partial byte stream but it's not true.
thank you :)